# How do I manage google groups and modify user attributes without domain wide delegation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-gsuite, gcp-iam

I want to give GSAs direct access to modify Google *users*. I can't find current docs on this so assuming it's not possible right now?

It looks like this is only possible for working with groups:
https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2020/08/new-api-cloud-identity-groups-google.html
[image]

I need to give a GSA access to read group membership and also modify user attributes.

Right now I:

- create an admin a G Suite user
- create a GSA with domain wide auth with these scopes

  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user

Impersonate the G Suite user with the GSA and modify user attributes like this:

```
service = create_directory_service("G SUITE USER")
service.users().update(userKey=uKey, body=myAttributes).execute()
```

Do I *still* need domain wide delegation to modify user attributes? Or is it supported now as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this guide to [create a Service Account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726?hl=en), turning on the [Admin SDK API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/?hl=en_US) (which allows the service account to provision/manage the users), and authorizing it.

The Service Account created can be used then to provision/manage the G-Suite users, here is a guide on [how to manage user accounts](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users) using the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory?hl=en_US), which is part of the Admin SDK.

In short, yes it is possible to manage users too, by using Service Accounts, not just groups.

Comment: `GSA will use the Service Account created` - the GSA is the Google Service Account though right? I don't have to have 2 user accounts just one GSA correct?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were referring to the Google Search Appliance, just edited the answer